# Javascript - find the index corresponding to an array key

Tags: javascript

Suppose there is a JavaScript array

```
myArray = {
    "key1" : value1
    ...
    "keyn" : valuen
}
```

My question is, can I find the integer index corresponding to, say, "key1" ?

I need both the value and the its integer position in the array!

Comment: This is technically an object literal, not an array. As such, its properties don't have an "index"

Comment: It would be possible to associate an integer to each property inside a `for in` iteration, but the properties wouldn't be guaranteed to come in the same order each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Slaks is correct, but maybe you can fudge it:

```
for(var key in myArray) {
    var sudoIndex = +key.match(/\d+/g)[0],
        value = myArray[key];
    // do stuff
}
```

This assumes your keys are numbered like in your example.

Comment: I used the `for in` and checked each property, while simultaneously incrementing an integer. The properties are iterated in desired order since I gave them in alphabetical order!

Comment: @eternalthinker: properties aren't guaranteed to preserve any particular order. Though you may have seen this in your limited tests, in other browsers (or other instances for the same browser), the behavior may be different. If you need properties to be ordered, you'll need to store the order in a separate data structure, such as an array containing the property names.

Answer (score 5):

No.
That is an object, not an array.

Object keys are unordered.

Answer (score 0):

For getting value you can do:

```
console.log(myArray.key1);
```